# How can i Cancel the before request send restangular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

#### this Code is not Canceling the request, why?

```
RestangularConfigurer.addFullRequestInterceptor(function (element, operation, route, url, headers, params, httpConfig) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    defer.reject();
    httpConfig.timeout = defer;
    return {
        element: element,
        headers: headers,
        params: params,
        httpConfig: httpConfig
    };
});
```

Comment: You return an object instead of the (rejected) promise.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign a promise to timeout:

```
httpConfig.timeout = defer.promise;
```

And resolve it (not reject):

```
defer.resolve();
```